# interpreter not found on PyCharm

Tags: python, console, pycharm

I installed Python but [there's no interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obmxl.png) on PyCharm to select.

Comment: Python *interpreter* is the correct term. Do you have Python installed? You should be able to click the '...' button, navigate to the correct folder where Python is installed, and select `python.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a configuration issue, you need to select python path by manually then it will work.
Check this link for details; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html